# how to implement dc.js in angular 4? I want to add dc.js in implement in my project, for refer URL as--https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

Tags: angular

I want to add dc.js in implement in my project, for refer URL as--https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

Answer (score 0):

To use external library you will have to install it with node package manager (npm). Executing such line:

```
npm install dc --save
```

You will have dc library in node_modules - folder with all dependencies that you will find in package.json file. --save option automatically adds that library into package.json.
After that you can use it in your code:

```
import * as dc from 'dc'
```